# How to bind Dynamic masking format on textbox which depend on another field

Tags: jquery, css, yii2-advanced-app

I am using yii2 advanced app. Now i have one dropdown and one textbox. Dropdown value are `Driving Licence` and another `Pan No.`

When User select `Driving Licence`, masking format is `9999 9999999999` and for `Pan No.` is `99-9999-9999`.

my _form.php

```
<div class="form-group" id="div_document">
                                    <?= $form->field($orderMasterModel, 'document')->dropDownList(['Driving Licence' => 'Driving Licence', 'Pan Card' => 'Pan Card'], ['placeholder' => 'Document']) ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="div_document_no">
                                    <?= $form->field($orderMasterModel, 'pan_no')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
                                            'mask' => '999-999-9999',
                                        ]) ?>
</div>
```

Now I don't know how to make depended mask format of textbox. Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can't do that without any kind of AJAX, the PHP runs in server at execution time so you can't change the mask conditionally without other programming.

Answer (score 2):

Here i find solution. Using Php it is not possible to give dynamic masking. so i use javascript.

1. First put `'data-plugin-inputmask'=>"inputmask_b1ea8b87"` in field where you need masking.

   ```
   <div class="col-md-6">
                                   <div class="form-group" id="div_document_no" style="display: none">
                                       <?= $form->field($orderMasterModel, 'pan_no')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Document No','data-plugin-inputmask'=>"inputmask_b1ea8b87"]) ?>
                                   </div>
   ```
2. Bind jquery.inputmask.bundle.js on view page.

   `list(,$mask)=Yii::$app->assetManager->publish('@bower/jquery.inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js');
   $this->registerJsFile($mask,['position' =>View::POS_END]);`
3. In javascript.

   ```
   $('#ordermaster-document').on('change', function() {
       if(this.value=='Pan Card')
       {
           var inputmask_b1ea8b87 = {"mask":"a{5}9999A{1}"};
       }else{
          var inputmask_b1ea8b87 = {"mask":"a{2}99 99999999999"}; 
       }
       $("#ordermaster-pan_no").inputmask(inputmask_b1ea8b87);
   ```

   });

By This dynamic masking can applied.